# Sort based Dictionary of Dictionary of Dictionary Values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this

```
d = {
    'Benefits': {
        1: {
            'BEN1': {
                'D': [{'description': 'D1'}],
                'C': [{'description': 'C1'}]
            }
        },
        2: {
            'BEN2': {
                'D': [{'description': 'D2'}],
                'C': [{'description': 'C2'}]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to sort dictionary based on KEY OF LAST VALUES(LIST).

FOR EXAMPLE

I am looking for get **dictionary value like 'C' IN first and 'D' in second**

I'm trying to get correct order. Here is code:

```
d1 = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))
```

Unfortunately didn't get correct result

This is my expected output

```
{'Benefits':
 {1:
  {'BEN1':
   {'C':[{'description': 'C1'}], 'D': [{'description': 'D1'}]
   }
  },
 2:
  {'BEN2':
   {'C': [{'description': 'C2'}], 'D': [{'description': 'D2'}]
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I am using python 3.5 . I am trying to get order like this

```
{'C':[{'description': 'C1'}], 'D': [{'description': 'D1'}]}
```

Comment: Could you please provide expected output and better explanation on how do you want it to be sorted.

Comment: @shaikmoeed: not true, they are sorted in insertion order since Python 3.6.

Comment: @shaikmoeed: no, since 3.6 normal `dict`and `OrderedDict` are exactly the same.

Comment: @aslamsha22 I can see that your code is working properly for me

Comment: @shaikmoeed: I am using python 3.5 ,The order will not correct all time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will sort any dictionary by its key and recursively sort *any* dictionary value that is also a dictionary by its key and makes no assumption as to the content of the dictionary being sorted. It uses an `OrderedDict` but if you can be sure it will always run on Python 3.6 or greater, a simple change can be made to use a `dict`.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {
    'Benefits': {
        1: {
            'BEN1': {
                'D': [{'description': 'D1'}],
                'C': [{'description': 'C1'}]
            }
        },
        2: {
            'BEN2': {
                'D': [{'description': 'D2'}],
                'C': [{'description': 'C2'}]
            }
        }
    }
}

def sort_dict(d):
    items = [[k, v] for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])]
    for item in items:
        if isinstance(item[1], dict):
            item[1] = sort_dict(item[1])
    return OrderedDict(items)
    #return dict(items)

print(sort_dict(d))
```

[See demo](http://ideone.com/CEASoM)

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))
```

This is not working because it is sorting only on the `Benefits` item. Here you want to sort inner items, so we have to reach the inner items and sort them.

```
d1 = {'Benefits': {}}
for a_benefit in d['Benefits']:
    d1['Benefits'][a_benefit] = {}
    for a_ben in d['Benefits'][a_benefit]:
        d1['Benefits'][a_benefit][a_ben] = dict(collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d['Benefits'][a_benefit][a_ben].items())))
```

Comment: You are creating an OrderedCollection (okay) and then taking its items to instantiate a standard `dict`, which may or may not be ordered depending upon which version of Python is being used. I am not following.

Comment: Oh, is it because you are assuming that the input only has one key at the highest level of dictionary (and you are also assuming it will always be named 'Benefits')? Will these assumptions always hold true in the future?

Comment: @RonaldAaronson Yes, I am making some assumptions. I believe your answer is perfect one.